# Can you load a random file each time you click the same button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have 4 contact forms we would like to rotate for testing. I don't want to run these in separate campaigns and for such a simple thing its overkill. Is it possible to have a group of say 4 forms and load them randomly ( a different form ) each time you click a button?

```
$(function() {
    $("a.random")click.(function){
    //?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
<form id="form0" class="test_form">
<form id="form1" class="test_form" style="display: none;">
<form id="form2" class="test_form" style="display: none;">
<form id="form3" class="test_form" style="display: none;">
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $("a.random")click.(function){
       $(".test_form").hide();
       var formNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);//will equal a number between 0 and 3
       $("#form" + formNumber).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Adam I don't think you will get numbers from the set {0, 1, 2, 3}

Comment: @Sime, Adam, very cool. so it is possible. Here's the next wrinkle, it is loaded in a jQuery Tools overlay as such <a href="Forms/SupportFormTest.php" rel="#overlayForm"> would I create a var for the href? or does this complicate things too much?

Comment: @Adam Also, I don't think that using round() will give you randomness. The chances for a zero or three are less then the chances for a one or a two. (twice as small, to be precise)

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design, I'm not familiar with jQuery Tools, you'll have to ask someone else

Comment: @Šime Vidas- I never realized that, you're right of course. I've seen the round used code a lot, but it certainly makes more sense to use floor. Thanks!

Comment: @Sime - would it be easier to make a "controller" file in PHP that does the random insertion and just point to it?

Comment: @Dirty I'm not familiar with PHP. What are controller files? If you want to add pages that contain a form to your page, consider Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

```
var n = Math.floor( Math.random() * 4 ) + 1;
```

This will give you a random integer number between 1 and 4. Based on that, you run different commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the forms like this:

```
<div id="forms">
  <form style="display:none;" ...>
    ...
  </form>
  <form style="display:none;" ...><!-- the second form -->
    ...
  </form>
  ...
</div>
<a href="#" id="randomForm">Show random form</a>
```

And then in your jQuery:

```
$('#randomForm').click(function() {
    var forms = $('#forms > form');
    forms.hide();
    forms.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * forms.length)).show();
});
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/tUMBp/).

Comment: see comment to Sime and Adam, is it possible to add it to a href as a var? I need to add it to a href for it to work in an overlay

Comment: @Dirty: I don't know what a jQuery Tools overlay is.. it's probably a good idea to ask a separate question

Answer (score 0):

This is verbose but something like this should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.random")click.(function){
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*5)
        switch (randomnumber) {
          case 1:
           $(this).attr("href",[url 1]);
           break;
          case 2:
           $(this).attr("href",[url 2]);
           break;
          case 3:
           $(this).attr("href",[url 3]);
           break;
          default:
           $(this).attr("href",[url 4]);
           break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr(...)` There is no need to copy-paste this expression for each choice.

Comment: Also wrong: `randomnumber` will be a number from 0 to 4, so your `default` case has more probability of running. You can easily do something like `var urls = ['url1','url2','url3','url4'];` and then `$(this).attr("href",urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);`. Now it's not even restricted to 4!

Comment: Ouch. Should've run this before posting...calling this my code review for the day and moving on

Answer (score 0):

Can we use a pure javascript and dom here, see if it works for you.

```
var arr = [form1, form2, form3, form4];

var fn = function(arr){
  var cur_frm = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  cur_frm.style.display = 'block';

  for(i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] != cur_frm) arr[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```